# audio not working on macbook pro 2017 with ubuntu 22.04 lts even after getting the audio output device to show in sound settings

Tags: sound, 22.04, alsa, macbook-pro

Tried installing this driver:"apt install wget make gcc linux-headers-generic"

and unmuted the speaker in alsamixer and my audio still does not work, even though I know there is nothing wrong with the speakers because i get the startup sound when iI boot up the mMacbook. in settings under sound it lists the audio device but will not play audio when i test the speakers or play a youtube video

Comment: The command `apt install wget make gcc linux-headers-generic` doesn't install any driver. `wget` is a tool for downloading files, `make` is a tool need for compiling, `gcc` is a C-complier collection, `linux-headers-generic` are the header files for the Ubuntu generic kernel.

Comment: Yeah I put Sudo in front of that command and even built the driver manually, however I don’t think that is the issue. The audio device shows under settings but audio still will not play.